# Plot several graphs in R

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2

I am trying to plot automatically several graphs with ggplot. I want to make a total of 23 stacked bar plot.

The original df (`train2016`) has variables in columns 25 to 48 and all of them have the values `c(0, 1)`.

I want to represent on Y axis the month (given in a column) - X axis the result of the count of 0 or 1 value of each variable.

I cannot see the result and there is no error showing. This is the code I wrote. I know there must be multiple errors

```
par(nfrow=c(4,6))
for (i in 25:48) {
  datos22 <- train2016 %>%
    group_by(month, train2016[i]) %>%
    summarise(count= n()) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(fill=train2016[i], x=count,y=month)) +
    geom_col() +
    ggtitle(" ") 
}
```

Comment: Your plots are saved in the loop as `datos22`. Add `print(datos22)` to the loop to plot them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `ggsave` to save the graphs

```
par(nfrow=c(4,6))

for (i in 25:48) {
  datos22 <- train2016 %>%
    group_by(month, train2016[i]) %>%
    summarise(count= n()) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(fill=train2016[i], x=count,y=month)) +
    geom_col() +
    ggtitle(" ") 
  ggsave(paste0("plot_", i, ".png")) 
}
```

Will save all the plots to independent files.